# Displaying audio waveforms in React

Tags: reactjs, audio, waveform, visualizer

So i´m building this webpage which allow users to upload a song, and the displayind that sound as a card on the home-page. Sort of like Soundcloud...

Im just getting to learn React, after coming from html, css and JS. So please understand im new to this all.

I´ve been researched the topic alot, and no one has seemed to work for me.

Ive been trying howler.js, and wavesurfer.js, without any luck of displaying waveforms.

have anyone else tried doing this before? someone who could maybe help out?

```
import { ErrorResponse } from '@remix-run/router';
import React from 'react'
import wavesurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'
import "./css/audio.css"
import { useRef } from 'react';

export const AudioVisualizer = (props) => {
// the homepage has a function to map through all the objects     in the 
// database, and in return i get every object. I then get the link from each
// object and pass this link into this function as an ARgument. 
let link = props; 
const audioRef = useRef();
console.log("here is props:  " + link);

try {

var audioTrack = wavesurfer.create({
    container: audioRef,
    wavecolor: "#eee",
    progressColor: "red",
    barWidth: 2,
});

audioTrack.load(link);
} catch (ErrorResponse)  {
    console.error("Something happened..");
    return ErrorResponse;
};

return (
    <div className='audio' ref={audioRef}>

    </div>
)
```

}

From there I have the actual Home.js page where I want to display the returned  from the function above.

the home.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../components/css/home/home.css';
import {collection, getDocs, onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {db} from '../firebase'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {ClipLoader} from 'react-spinners';
import {AudioVisualizer} from "../components/audioVisualizer"


const Home = () => {
const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const navigate = useNavigate();


useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const retrieveSongs = onSnapshot(
        collection(db, "songs"), 
        (snapshot) => {
            let arrayList = [];
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                arrayList.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
            });
            setSongs(arrayList);
            setLoading(false);

        }, 
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );

    return () => {
        retrieveSongs();
    };
    
}, []);

return (
    <div className='home_wrapper'>
        <>
        
            {loading ? 
                <ClipLoader color="#36d7b7" />
            :

                <div className='homepage_container'>

                    {   songs.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <article key={data.id} className='card'>
                                <div className='card_content'>
                                    <img className='card_image' src={data.image} />

                                    <div className='song_info'>
                                    <h2>{data.title}</h2>
                                    <h4>{data.artist}</h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className='audioplayer'>
                                    {AudioVisualizer(data.audio)}
                                    {/* <ReactAudioPlayer src={data.audio} autoPlay controls/> */}
                                    {/* <Waveform className="audio_file" audio={data.audio}/> */}
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div className='card_content_extra'>
                                    <button onClick={() => navigate('/update/${data.id}')}>Edit</button>
                                    <button >Listen</button>
                                </div>

                                {/* <div id="waveform"></div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>Play/Pause
                                    </button> */}
                            </article>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            }
        </>
    </div>
)
```

}

```
export default Home
```

UPDATE::

So as i described in my comment. When i am mapping through the songs object from my database, the waveform wont display. When i pass a direct link to the component it works. but when im passing my object "audio", and getting the  value, , it will not show the waveform. When i try to console.log(data.audio) // it returns undefined.

see for yourself: [As you can see from the console.log, it acts weird..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sfM2.png)

Comment: please add more information. what has not worked for you? do you maybe have some code, that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the DOM element is accessed by the `.current` property Not the reference object created by React.

You could use the `useEffect` hook, to load the data.

Then create the AudioVisualizer Component in the JSX react way and pass the link to the wavesurfer.

Also the wavesurfer dom object need to have some size.

Have a look at this mini example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import wavesurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'

const AudioVisualizer = (props) => {

  const audioRef = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (audioRef.current){
      let audioTrack = wavesurfer.create({
          container: audioRef.current,
      });
      audioTrack.load(props.link);
    }
  })

  return <div style={{minWidth: "200px"}} className='audio' ref={audioRef}></div> 
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <AudioVisualizer link={"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/science_fiction/creature_distortion_white_noise.ogg"}></AudioVisualizer>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.querySelector('#root')
).render(<App />)
```

Comment: thank you! Will take slik at this in a second. Will update and Get back to you. Thank you for the explanation. I was thinking of trying out the useEffect hook. The .current tving is new to me. Will look that up!

Comment: OK, so i tried it! it actually works, and i am so happy!!! jesus thanks man! i have 1 problem left to go tho. My audio files wont display, but the link you provided did work. My files are stored in Firebase storage + firestore. so the firestore collection "songs" have a key that is audio. and the value is a string that reference the file in the storage. so as you can see from my code above, i map through the songs array, and i return the wavesurfer for each song-object in the DB. My problem is with the .map() function, when im passing the url to the component it will not work..

Comment: i updated the problem in the post. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Would you be able to contact me PM? would love to get help figuring out a couple of problems if you would be so kind :)

Comment: can you show me what the data object looks like. e.g. by just console.log(data)?